# "local variable 'resol' referenced before assignment" but can't seem to understand why

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to make a function that would solve simple equations but I came a error after adding a chains of "if" that would define a local variable that would later be printed

```py
def re_eq(eq):
    numbers = ""
    for char in eq:
        if char.isalpha():
            incog = char
        elif char.isdigit():
            numbers += char
            numbers += " "
        elif char.isascii():
            if char ==  "+" or "-" or "*" or "/":
                sym = char
    num1, num2 = numbers.split()
    if sym == "+":
        resol = int(num2) - int(num1)
    elif sym == "-":
        resol = int(num2) + int(num1)
    elif sym == "*":
        resol = int(num2) / int(num1)
    elif sym == "/":
        resol = int(num2) * int(num1)
    print(incog, " = ", resol)
```

the problem only started to happen after adding the second chain "if" and "elif" before that it was just:

```py
    resol = int(num2) * int(num1)
    print(incog, " = ", resol)
```

no problems were happening then

when calling the equation it should print "x = 2" or something similar depending on the values used but instead I am getting

```
"local variable 'resol' referenced before assignment"
```

I cant understand why since resol its being referenced before of actually printing it; I could just use "return" or maybe a global variable but I want to atleast understand what is happening and why for the sake of learning

(the function when called is called with a parameter with a input of "4 + x = 9")

Comment: initialize `resol` as `number` is initialized. The error occurs when none of the second if statement is `true` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if char ==  "+" or "-" or "*" or "/":` doesn't mean what you think it means. It's effectively the same as `if True:`, because if `char` doesn't equal `'+'`, the expression is equal to `'-'`, which is truthy because it's of nonzero length. You probably meant `if char in '+-*/':`. This means that your `if/elif` part is not exhaustive and you managed to never assign `resol`, but still tried to print it.

Comment: I see I understand now, however what I wanted to do in that line was that if char was equal to +, -, * or / it would continue and be assigned to sym, how could I do that?

Comment: @Aulmeies Did you try `if char in '+-*/':` instead?

Answer (score 4):

The `if-elif` chain does not end with an `else` clause. Which means there might be some possibility where control does not enter into any of the `if-elif` blocks, during which the variable `resol` does not get created at all and leads to the error.

Initialize `resol` to some default value before the `if-elif` chain or add an `else` clause and initialize `resol` to a default value in it.

Also, change this line

```
if char ==  "+" or "-" or "*" or "/":
  ...
```

to

```
if char in {"+", "-", "*", "/"}:
  ...
```

The expression `if char ==  "+" or "-" or "*" or "/":` will always evaluate to `True`. `or` has a lower precedence than `==` which means it actually gets evaluated in the order `if (char ==  "+") or "-" or "*" or "/":` Therefore, even if `char` is not equal to `"+"`, "-" is a nonempty str which is always `True`. The control enters into the `if` statement and `sym` gets assigned whatever value `char` has even if it's not what you intended.

Comment: But if sym is equal to one of the conditions listed then what?

when calling it re_eq(eq) should be working since the parameter used is equal to "4 + x = 9" yet it doesn't